# Using least square to fit a parametric curve

Tags: least-squares, parametric-equations

I have a curve represented as a parametric function, z(t)=(x(t), y(t)), x=f(t), y=g(t). If I wanna find a approximate curve using least square(using polynomial funtions), am I supposed to get one for x and one for y or just one for z?

Comment: Namely you want to have approximation to 5D curve?

Comment: No, just a 2d parametric curve. Thanks.

Comment: OK. What order of polynomial? It would be great if you could link to a CSV file or `MAT` file with coordinates and values you have.

Comment: The order if 3. Actually, I figured it out. Anyway, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: So please share the solution here and mark as answered.

Comment: So the problem is like this: given a parametric curve r(t) = (x(t), y(t)), find a approximate cubic polynomial curve. I collect multiple points in x(t) and y(t) and then use least square to find a corresponding curve for x(t), y(t). The final approximate curve is like r'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t))

Comment: I know this, I wanted to answer you. But paste your answer and your code an answer for others to come.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is like this: given a parametric curve r(t) = (x(t), y(t)), find a approximate cubic polynomial curve. I collect multiple points in x(t) and y(t) and then use least square to find a corresponding curve for x(t), y(t). The final approximate curve is like r'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t))